# python pandas groupby function mean() always skip certain columns

Tags: pandas

I was trying to get the average price of different area of a city, so this is my procedure of dealing with my data:
1.I check the column that I want to use, delete all the null value, it was '---' here, i drop them,
2.then I use groupby method on my['area'] column, then use mean() afterward.
But the price column always get skipped by mean(), I've already check the elements inside, and there's nothing more besides float and int, I have no idea what else I haven't do, pls help.

```
price1['price/square feet']=price1['price/square feet'].dropna()
price1 = price1[price1['price/square feet'] != '---']

#print(price1['price/square feet'].tolist())
#a=[]
#for x in range(len(p)):
#    if type(p[x])!= float:
#        a.append(p[x])   
#print(a)

section=price1.groupby('area')
average_price_per_section=section.mean()
```

and the results always doesn't show ['price'] column but others.

Comment: `price1['price/square feet']` is almost certainly `dtype: object`, so mean ignores it, despite the values being int/floats themselves. You should `price1['price/square feet'] = pd.to_numeric(price1['price/square feet'])` before you groupby

Comment: @ALollz Thanks, but at which step did I change that column to object? Is there a certain topic talk about this? I want to take a look